# Informatica code check-in Hooks from Repository

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working on a testing automation project and I am able to automate end to end test cases but in my scope I have to enable functionality to run test-case when a workflow is checked-in to repository. For this I need a trigger with information like what workflow and in which folder is checked it's checked in. Unfortunately I am unable to get anything till now and my admins are also not sure if this can be achieved. Any lead will be a great help.
Even if I can get the logs of workflow check-in, I can process them in real-time to get this information.

Comment: Google repository tables and see if some field saves the check-in info. I am not sure but have a hunch that this might be the place to look at.

Comment: Checked and found few links for rep table's schema but nothing there for Check-In info. Could you please help me with some solid link.